# show all custom posts types in home page

Tags: custom-post-types, query, homepage

Hi i am working on custom post types in wordpress presently we are using below code to display  the custom posts, but the thing is the custom post types are keep on increasing,

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_my_post_types_to_query' );

function add_my_post_types_to_query( $query ) {
    if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'books', 'recipes', 'movie' ) );
    return $query;
}
```

from above query i am calling the posts from books,recipes and movie but due increase of post_types i cant add all the post types in the above query.

dose anybody have idea how to call all the posts from all post_types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_my_post_types_to_query' );

function add_my_post_types_to_query( $query ) {
  if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
    $query->set( 'post_type', 'any' );
  return $query;
}
```

refer to http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_Parameters

Comment: how to get only public post_types here is my script
<?php query_posts('post_type=any'); ?>

  <?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember the appropriate query for all public post types is `post_type` equals string `any`.

You can use [`get_post_types()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_post_types/) to retrieve a list, but be careful with arguments, since not post types are meant for public/front display.

Comment: From [WP_Query's Codex Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query):
"'any' - retrieves any type except revisions and types with 'exclude_from_search' set to true."
This also implicitly excludes `attachment` since it has the non-default `post_status` of "inherit".